# In VS Code How Can I Automatically Import "assert" in a React Node App?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, import

In Visual Studio Code you can automatically import most things by moving the focus to the imported term, and then using the "quick fix" feature (`CTRL + .` for me).  You'll then be given an option to have VS Code add an import for the term to the top of your file for you ... unless the term is `assert`.

(**NOTE:** I believe you need to have `"checkJs": true` in your `jsconfig.js` for this to work ... or else be using Typescript.)

What's strange is, the "assert" module *is* available, as part of Node itself! It seems that VS Code just isn't *aware* that it's available, and I'm not sure how to make it aware.

Is there any way (eg. a VS Code setting, a `jsconfig.json` option, etc.) that would to make it recognize the existence of the `assert` module when it comes to automatic imports?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I believe since `assert` is a keyword in many languages, VSCode doesn't really see it as a "missing" item for the quick fix macro.  This would seem to be a bug in VSCode, but it's rather obscure and I can't find anything to corroborate that theory.

Comment: Good idea, but the thing is, it does see it as missing.  If I type `assert(1);` I get a squiggly line under `assert` with the warning "Cannot find name 'assert'.ts(2304)".  Normally I could quick fix and import, but in the quick fix there is no option to import anything at all.

Comment: if the import fixes the problem and makes the program run you can file a request to expand the Quick-Fix-Provider and add the import assert.

Comment: @rioV8 so you're basically suggesting this is a bug and I should file it as such?  I actually started out doing that, but then I wanted to check and make sure I wasn't missing something first, before I bothered the maintainers ... thus this post :-)  But if the bounty expires I guess that will be "proof" that it truly is a bug (and if you provide that as an answer, and no one provides a better one, I'll try to accept it at the end, so the bounty at least goes to someone who tried to help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a bug and it should work for all build in modules.

---

**Long explanation when it works and when not.**

It can propose to import assert but in a strange way.

I have a simple JavaScript project with a `jsconfig.json` file with

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "checkJs": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

As you have mention `"checkJs": true` is essential to get the required CodeAction (QuickFix) options.

Or you can add as a first line in the `.js` files

```
//@ts-check
```

My `app.js` file is very simple

```
assert(5 > 7, "Always False");
```

I get the red squiggles, but no import suggestion in the Quick Fix list.

If I add any `require` statement for a build in module I get import suggestions in the Quick Fix list (`import 'assert' from module "console"` and `import 'assert' from module "assert"`)

```
var zlib = require('zlib');
assert(5 > 7, "Always False");
```

If I choose one of the imports I get

```
var zlib = require('zlib');
const assert = require('assert');
assert(5 > 7, "Always False");
```

And running the script in Node.js throws on the assert as expected.

```
Debugger attached.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
assert.js:374
    throw err;
    ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Always False
[snip....]
  generatedMessage: false,
  code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
  actual: false,
  expected: true,
  operator: '=='
}
Process exited with code 1
```

If I have an `app.js` with

```
var gzip = zlib.createGzip();
```

I can't get a Quick Fix to import zlib.

Adding the import myself makes the script run.

```
var zlib = require('zlib');
var gzip = zlib.createGzip();
```

I wonder which modules can generate a Quick Fix suggestion.

Comment: If you could just put "It's a bug" at the top, and then put all those details after (or just delete them entirely) I could accept this answer.

Comment: @machineghost I moved the last line to the top and added "Long explanation" disclaimer